# Retrieve data from json file without previously know content

Tags: jquery, json

In my spring project, I have several json files generate with json-taglibs, with a structure similar to this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<json:object>
    <json:array name="item" var="item" items="${lista}">
          <json:object>
             <json:property name="id" value="${item.id}"/>
             <json:property name="login" value="${item.login}"/>
             <json:property name="pnome" value="${item.first_name}"/>
             <json:property name="unome" value="${item.last_name}"/>
             <json:property name="email" value="${item.email}"/>
          </json:object>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

I use this files to generate tables with this jquery code:

```
function load_content(lista, target){
    var atributos = [];
    target.find("thead.header").each(function(){
        var temp = $(this).text();
        console.log(temp);
        atributos.push(temp);
    });

    var url = lista;
    $.get(url, function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.item, function(index, item){
            var row = $('<tr id=user'+item.id+'>');

            for(var i=0; i<atributos.length; i++) {
                if(atributos[i] == '#') {
                    row.append('<td></td>');
                }
                else if(atributos[i] == '') {
                    var col = $('<td>');
                    target.find("tfoot.actions").each(function(){
                        var nome = $(this).data("nome");
                        var action = $(this).data("action");
                        col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary link" data-action="'+action+'/'+item.id+'">'+nome+'</button>');
                    });
                    row.append(col);
                }
                else {
                    var token = "item."+atributos[i];
                    row.append('<td>'+item.login+'</td>');
                }
            }

            target.find("tbody.content").append(row);
        });
    });
}
```

I need some help with this part of the code:

```
else {
  var token = "item."+atributos[i];
  row.append('<td>'+item.login+'</td>');
}
```

this parte should read the properties from json file (in the example, login, pnome, unome, email) and add to the row. The problem it's each json file has your own properties, and I need this code works for all of them.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Now sure what you are looking for but maybe you want: `var token = item[atributos[i]];`

Comment: Ok, This will do what I want just fine.